# Mysql Update Scripts to change values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have table with values like

```
Book ID    email1               email2
101        abcd@test.com     abcd@test.com
102        vxyz@test.com     vxyz@test.com
105        pqrs@test.com     pqrs@test.com
```

I want to update all the values of email1 and email2 
from test.com to   testmail.com

```
e.g abcd@test.com  to abcd@testmail.com,
and  vxyz@test.com   to   vxyz@testmail.com
```

how to write update query for this in mysql

Comment: Can you show what you have tried please.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET email1 = REPLACE(email1,'@test.com ','@testemail.com '), 
    email2 = REPLACE(email2,'@test.com ','@testemail.com ')
```